# Hide window when other application in fullscreen mode (pseudo fullscreen)

Tags: winapi, fullscreen

I have an application for Windows which is basically a toolbar on top of all windows.

Unfortunately, our users ask why does it overlap a fullscreen video playing in Google Chrome. Since the application works with no issues along with other fullscreen applications (such as games), it seems to be a pseudo fullscreen mode. How do we hide the toolbar in such cases?

Right now there is only one idea: keep an eye on MoveWindow, compare window class name against a predefined list and rectangle against screen size then deduce whether it is the 'pseuso fullscreen' mode. Any better ideas?

Comment: One option that may or may not work for you is to use `SHAppBarMessage` to register your toolbar as an app bar. You will then be told when to hide due to full screen.

Comment: What about letting the user hide the toolbar?